# Mysql Subquery Where Not In

Tags: mysql, database

Hi there I can retrieve results from a product and price table using innner join:

```
SELECT product.name, price.code, price.price FROM product 
INNER JOIN price ON product.productid=price.productid;
```

All well and good here.

However I have another table called items which has a list of codes that are also in the price table (eg price.price).

I want to display the products that are not in the items table  by using WHERE NOT IN  so I have tried a subquery:

```
SELECT product.name, price.code, price.price FROM product 
INNER JOIN price ON product.productid=price.productid 
WHERE code NOT IN (select code from items);
```

My comparison conditions is based on codes that are in the price table and items table.  I get an empty set returned so not sure what I need to do to correct this??

Cheers

Comment: The code you've shown us does what you describe you want to acheive. If the results are nt what you expect then either you've not described the problem well or the data is not as you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what is the problem with your query, but there is one possible problem with `null` value when using the `IN` predicate, if `code` has any nullable values, the condition will be false as the values will be unknow, so it will be safe if you try `left join` instead:

```
SELECT product.name, price.code, price.price 
FROM product 
INNER JOIN price ON product.productid=price.productid 
LEFT JOIN items ON items.code = price.code 
WHERE items.code IS NULL
```

Comment: It would be interesting with an explanation of what is wrong with OP's approach.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg - Not sure, but see my edit for some possible problem.

Comment: Thanks! As symcbean mentions in a comment, there seems to be nothing obviously broken with OP's code, so good with your clarification.

Comment: Hi there, I tried your example which doesn't work.  Unless I change it to the following which does work:  "....ON items.code = price.code WHERE.."  The product table doesn't have the code!!! Its in the price table.  This DOES give me results so I just need to check that the results are in fact not in first condition

Comment: @Hexana - Yes, sorry, you are right, I thought the product table is one that have the code column, I fixed it see my edit.

Comment: Fantastic this has been very helpful indeed Mahmoud. I appreciate your help very much!!